# eclipse setting build path

Tags: maven, classpath, buildpath

I want to configure build path in my maven project.
I want to use the directory ${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/apt as a source classpath.

Below image is a screenshot of youtube video and the eclipse in that video, has target/generated/annotation classpath. I want to do that same thing on my project.

[image]

[image]

Simply,

I want my maven web project has a additional classpath : "target/generated-sources/apt"

How do I do that ??

Comment: Its not very clear from your question, how are you planning to generate those classes?

Comment: I am studying spring data jpa criteria API, and that skill requires automation of creating StaticMetamodel object. To create automatically that object, I should add some maven plugins generating StaticMetamodel-annotated object in a **designated place**, and the place could be "${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/apt", also that place should be accessible by eclipse, in other words, it should be a classpath. so I have to manage build path.